# How to launch the activity for user to key in information once only in android?

Tags: android

This is my login activity code. I just want to launch my user information for user to key in their information once only after that next time when user login will straight open to main activity. Can anyone help me or teach me?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonSignIn;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignup;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Boolean session_tag = prefs.getBoolean("session", false);
    if(session_tag)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

    }



    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
        //profile activity here
    }



    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    textViewSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);
    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(this);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}



private void userLogin(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execction further
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;
    }
    //if validations are ok

    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
    progressDialog.show();


    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        //start the profle activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong email or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
}



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonSignIn){
        userLogin();

    }
    if (view == textViewSignup){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class));


    }
}
```

}

Comment: use shared preferences for store and retrieve value

Comment: how to use boolean in Shared Preferences. I have see many video but still don't how to use. Need to add in which lines? After Login Activity will launch UserInformation Activity, this activity just open once only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bleach If You want to Send some Value in one activity to another activity You have three way to do this action in android studio 
1. You use Intent . Help of Intent You send value one activity to another.
2. Shared Preferences .Help of Shared Preferences You Make a Session and send Value one Activity to another .
3. Bundle . Help Of Bundle You share a Data One activity to another when You Send data one Activity to another You have compress data in Bundle and send Into another activity.
Thank You .
If This Post Help You Please Tell me. I am waiting Your Reply.

Comment: But the three way i also don't know how to write.

Comment: Ok I tell You Brefily Which way You want to Know.

Comment: i don't know which want can achieve what i want. What i want is:
user first time login then will display user information activity after user key in the information then will go to main activity.
After that, the same user login again, it will straight login and go to main activity, the user information activity will only display one time.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_text", string); 
startActivity(intent); use This code to wrap data

Comment: and another activity use String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_text"); take the data

Comment: or just write a simple code for me to have reference.

Comment: First Of All You tell Me You Move which activity to another

Comment: @Bleach and You Please Upvote My answer Then I am help You Regularly

Comment: First time Login activity > User Information activity > Main Activity

Comment: Next time this same user login will become Login activity>Main activity

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean in Shared Preferences.

In the `onComplete` method, add `boolean loggedIn = true` and add this to SharedPreferences, then start MainActivity.

At the start of LoginActivity, access SharedPreferences and check if boolean true.
If its true start MainActivity.

SharedPreferences guide : [SharedPrefs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: how to use boolean in Shared Preferences. I have see many video but still don't how to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonSignIn;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignup;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
        //profile activity here
    }

    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    textViewSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);
    buttonSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(this);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 

    Boolean session_tag = prefs.getBoolean("session", false);
         if(session_tag)
       {
          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
       }
}


private void userLogin(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execction further
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //stopping the function execution further
        return;
    }
    //if validations are ok

    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging In...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //start the profle activity
                       prefs.edit().putBoolean("session", true).apply();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong email or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonSignIn){
        userLogin();

    }
    if (view == textViewSignup){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class));


    }
}

}
```

if you want check boolean variable then here i wrote some code:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("session", true).apply();
```

to get value Boolean

```
session_tag = prefs.getBoolean("session", false);
```

Comment: can i know this need to add in which line?

Comment: i need to add before the if(task.isSuccessful()) to check the boolean is true or false? Sorry about that i'm new to android studio.

Comment: thank you so much at least i have a reference to see. Thank you

Comment: i still not understand. Just add this inside my code? Need to add at where? And the getDefaultSharedPreferences(); inside the () need to write what?

Comment: Can you modify inside my code? I really not understand how to use this sharedpreference.

Comment: The code is ok but the it skip my login page for user login. What i prefer is when the user open the app the login page will start first then if the user is first time login then will launch UserInformation page after that will go to MainActivity. Next time when this user login again it will straight launch MainActivity page.

Comment: @Bleach ok then cut my onstart method and paste in oncreate method

Comment: i have edited my code can help me check whether i paste it correct? Because when i start the app straight error.

Comment: the code ok already but it still skip my login page for user login with email and password.

Comment: or i need to add that sharedpreference to my userinformation page? Because this page just will launch for first time.

Comment: this is the code which works. now where to put it, it's your issue.

Comment: if it solves your issue then please mark it as correct.

Comment: can i know that the code is open the activity page just one time only or it straight skip the activity page?

Comment: this code will show login page for only some seconds and then it will proceed to next activity. as we are checking in oncreate that prefs is set or not.